# Exclude primary key attributes from a sequelize query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query from multiple tables inner joined together. I need to group them by on a nested `include` model but the sequelize query throws the primary key every time, even if I mention the attributes as: `attributes:[]`.

However `attributes:[]` is working for nested `include` models.

Comment: Looks like the id is added because Sequelize is trying to pull in that model. I am trying to accomplish the same thing as you but haven't been able to figure out the solution using `findAll`.

Answer (score 41):

You can exclude any attributes by passing an `exclude` array into the `attributes` option:

```
MyModel.findAll({
  attributes: {exclude: ['some_field']}
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the primary key in this case. I have a similar query I'm trying to achieve and listing the primary key in the exclude array has no effect.

Comment: @JCF Downvote? Can you confirm this in the Sequelize docs or code base? I'm [looking at the code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/d2f33830b8bec035ac175acd3ec7622b694e00b8/types/lib/model.d.ts#L477-L486) and don't see where it disallows exclude a primary key.

Answer (score 5):

For included models use `attributes: ['prop_name']`

Remember `include`/`exclude` will not affect nested tables use `through: { attributes:[]}`

```
Model.addScope('scope_name', {
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
      include: [
        {
          model: models.role,
          as: 'roles',
          attributes: ['name'],
          through: {
            attributes: []
          }
        }
      ]
```

More details can be found here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4074#issuecomment-153054311

Answer (score 2):

I want to add that you can explicitly list the attributes you want and that they work on nested inner joins as follows:

```
const my_model = await MyModel.findById(id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: AnotherModel,
      attributes: [ 'displayName', 'email' ] // only these attributes returned
    },
    { model: YetAnotherModel,
      include: [{
        model: AnotherModel,
        attributes: [ 'id', 'displayName', 'email' ]
      }]
    }
  ]
})
```

Your returned Object should look like:

```
{
  // ...MyModel attributes
  ,
  AnotherModel: {
    displayName: '...',
    email: '...',
  },
  YetAnotherModel: {
    // ...YetAnotherModel's attributes
    ,
    AnotherModel: {
      id: '...',
      displayName: '...',
      email: '...',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who still are looking for the solution to this problem.
From https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/4029, if you add `raw: true` to the query, it removes the primary key.

```
Model.findOne({ 
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('field')), 'sum'],
  ],
  raw: true
})
```